# Tiny screws/bolts/other fastener - what is it and how do I get it out?

Tags: tools

[image]dont know what these fasteners are or how to remove them. Some kind of bolt i think.

Bolt head is totally smooth and round. Screws into a circular receptical with a tiny circular divit. Can't figure out what tool could get any traction on either the head or the receptical.

[image]

Comment: A photo would be helpful

Comment: Ah yes of course

Comment: That is what is called a _rivet_.

Answer (score 9):

It's a rivet.  You can drill it out with a metal [twist drill](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/twist_drill), [countersink](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Countersink), or countersink deburring bit.